# Unable to load jQuery to Zend framework project

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, load

I want to load jQuery to existing project, I am sure that ZendX is existed in extras/library inside the library project.

i add these two lines to application.ini

```
 resources.view.helperPath.ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper = "ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper"
 pluginPaths.ZendX_Application_Resource = "ZendX/Application/Resource"
```

then in the bootstrap file I add this method

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet('/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css')
            ->setLocalPath('/js/jquery-1.7.1.min')
            ->setUiLocalPath('/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js');
 }
```

and I am sure from the path of jquery and css files.
   and in the layout.phtml I add this line

```
 echo $this->jQuery;
```

but this error occor

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'JQuery' was not found in the registry; 
used paths: ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/' in E:\GCC\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Loader\PluginLoader.php:412
 Stack trace: #0 E:\GCC\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('JQuery') 
 #1 E:\GCC\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'jQuery') 
 #2 E:\GCC\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(344): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('jQuery')
 #3 [internal function]: Zend_View_Abstract->__call('jQuery', Array) 
 #4 C:\AppServ\www\zendApps\inspection\application\Bootstrap.php(38): Zend_View->jQuery()
 #5 E:\GCC\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap->_initViewHelpers() 
 #6 E:\GCC\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php in E:\GCC\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Loader\PluginLoader.php on line 412
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `echo $this->jQuery();` instead of `jQuery`.

You don't need register two times the jQuery helper path. One time in the application.ini should be enough.

Also, before getting a resource from the bootstrap, **ALWAYS** ensure this resource has been "boostrapped" before with: `$this->boostrap('view');`.

Comment: It doesn't work, jQuery is the variable  but jQuery() is a method, and it's convenient not to work;

Comment: You /ZendX/ directory is located in the /library/ directory, right? What if you `var_dump()` something or `die;` in `ZendX_Application_Resource_Jquery`, is this Class called at least?

Answer (score 0):

in your "layout.phtml" add the following:

```
$this->jQuery()->enable(); //enabling jquery
$this->jQuery()->uiEnable(); //enabling jquery-ui
echo $this->jQuery(); //
```

--OR--

at the end of your "_initViewHelpers()" add:

```
$view->jQuery()->enable(); //enabling jquery for all the views
$view->jQuery()->uiEnable(); //enabling jquery-ui for all the views
```

and then in each of your view or in the head section of your layout:

```
<?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?> //dont forget the () or it will not recognize the helper
```